# ReactJS: How can I list all the properties of a state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS but I have experience with Python and C++.

What I want to do is a function (or maybe a class?) that takes as input some object and displays all its properties of its state in the screen.

I don't know what those properties may be, I don't know how many there are, and come to think it, those properties may have their own properties.

Is there some kind of function capable of cycling through all the properties in the state?, what other approaches could I use?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). 
It returns an array with all properties name.

You can also use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), wich return all the values of the keys.

e.g.

```js
const state = {
    hey: 123,
    name: 'edu'
}

console.log(Object.keys(state))
```

And if you are using react you can use `Object.keys` with `.map` and display all the properties of the state (or any object).

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        name: 'edu',
        hey: 123
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                {Object.keys(this.state).map(key => <div key={key}>{key}</div>)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

You could also use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) wich will transform all the object into a json. 
This way you will be able to see all properties and values of the object.

Just be **careful** because you might get an error if the object have a circular reference.

Comment: This answer will only work if the properties doesn't have an inner property. @Dominic has the right answer

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can convert the object to an array and map over it, e.g:

```
function renderProps(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => (
    <div key={key}>{key}: {JSON.stringify(value)}</div>
  ));
}
```

Usage:

```
return (
  <div>
    <p>State:</p>
    {renderProps(this.state)}
    <p>Props:</p>
    {renderProps(this.props)}
  </div>
)
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/renderprops-1g9cd

You should not render `value` without converting it to a string (e.g. `JSON.stringify`) since if `value` is an object or array it will throw an unhandled exception.